# In C#, what does task.oncomplete do?

Tags: c#, task

I don't understand a sentence in the book C#5.0 in a nutshell P570, it says:

> If s synchronization context is present, oncomplete automatically
>   captures it and posts the continuation to that context. This is very
>   useful in rich client applications, as it bounces the continuation
>   back to the UI thread.

I don't know what does "bounce back" mean, is the thing in oncomplete() done in the main thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is basically saying that the code defined inside the oncomplete will execute on the main thread for ui based applications.  This is highly useful because you should only ever modify the state of UI components on the main thread.  For instance, to update a label upon completion of some work that a Task has done.

Comment: I don't know what does execute on the main thread mean? because the main thread should be doing something else.

Comment: Every UI based app has a main thread that is responsible for processing user events and drawing and manipulating UI controls to respond to the current state of the app.  When you run a task, that task may typically run on a different thread but many times when that task completes you want to update the UI that something has changed.  When you do execute your oncomplete continuation .net will make sure it runs back on the main thread, often called the UI thread since that is the thread that should only ever modify the UI controls.

Comment: The excerpt from the book is essentially telling you that you do not have to worry about switching the context back to the UI/main thread, which is nice, because as Ralph said you only want to update UI elements via the UI thread and not a background thread; otherwise you run the risk of creating deadlock, race conditions or other types of thread contention issues. In short, be happy that `task.oncomplete` does this for you.